# How to remove the UTC info from a time stamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, utc

I have a postgresql table that has a time value but it's stored without time zone information.  I'd like to convert it to UTC time, but format it a specific way.
I have a syntax error somewhere and I don't know how to fix it.  I have the following sql query :

```
testdb=# select id, starttime at TIME ZONE 'UTC',endtime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', dtc, etcd from fre order by id;
```

And it returns data like this:

```
     id     |  timezone   |  timezone   | dtc |        etcd        
-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-------------------------
 143322 | 13:00:00+00 | 00:00:00+00 | 0000000   | 8899703
 990222 | 05:00:00+00 | 05:00:00+00 | 0000000   | 45007
 452256 | 05:00:00+00 | 05:00:00+00 | 0000000   | 33303
 123118 | 05:08:00+00 | 00:00:00+00 | 1111100   | 8899701
```

I'd like to remove the "+00" reference in the starttime / endtime fields. 
I found another post here on stackoverflow that suggested using the to_char() method, and used this example:

```
testdb=# select to_char(now(), 'HH24:MI:SS');
 to_char  
----------
 09:55:48
(1 row)
```

So I adapted it and tried this:

```
testdb=# select to_char(now() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS');
 to_char  
----------
 14:55:58
(1 row)
```

Now I'm trying to apply this to my original query like so:

```
testdb=# select to_char(starttime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') from fre;
ERROR:  function to_char(time with time zone, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: select to_char(starttime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC', 'HH24:MI:SS') f...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT 1**

In case it helps...

```
testdb=# \d+ fre;
                           Table "public.fre"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
-----------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id       | character varying(40)  | not null  | extended | 
 etcd      | character varying(40)  | not null  | extended | 
 starttime | time without time zone |           | plain    | 
 endtime   | time without time zone |           | plain    | 
 startdate | date                   |           | plain    | 
 enddate   | date                   |           | plain    | 
 dtc       | bit(7)                 |           | extended |
```

Comment: Why do you use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` in the first place? Your columns does not contain time zones.

Comment: @pozs I need the time to be converted to UTC format.   Didn't know how else to do it.  If there's a better way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it back to timestamp without time zone:

```
(starttime at TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamp without time zone
```